# How to use WHERE clause with Phoenix UPSERT

Tags: apache-phoenix

Looks like UPSERT doesn't support a WHERE clause.

But people have used workaround like following:

```
UPSERT INTO test.MyTable(col1, col2) SELECT col3, col4 FROM test.TempTable WHERE col5 = ABC
```

Does that mean if I have a use case where I need to update all the columns of the `MyTable` based on some key, I need to add the data to be updated in another `TempTable` then use a command similar to above to update data of the `MyTable`.  Please let me know if my understanding is correct.  Somehow adding data in another table just to update source table does not seems correct.

Comment: Your syntax [appears to be valid](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#upsert_select).  But, are you using really using `WHERE col5 = ABC`?  You need to put single quotes around `'ABC'` if you intend for it be a string literal.

Comment: Thanks, Tim for your response.  But I do not like the idea of creating a temp table keeping all the data to be updated into it by the key of the main table, then updating the main table with the data from the temp table.  Is the creation of tempTable necessary.